# Java WebSocket signalling server for WebRTC

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, jetty, webrtc

I'm trying to get a java/jetty websocket signalling server set up for a simple Chatroom system that uses webrtc. This is just precursor to a multiplayer game I'm wanting to make. What I'm stuck with is how to notify other peers when somebody joins a chatroom, And how to tell this new peer about who is already in the chatroom. Also on the client, the websocket.onopen event does not seem to be firing, but on the server onOpen is fired when a client connects.

I've used some of Muaz's code but I can't really find compatible examples. I'm obviously missing the SDP part.

```
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/DataChannel.js"> </script>
<script>
var chatRoom = document.getElementById('chat-room');
var chatOutput = document.getElementById('chat-output');
var chatInput = document.getElementById('chat-input');
chatInput.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    channel.send(this.value);
    chatOutput.innerHTML = 'Me: ' + this.value + '<hr />' 
                         + chatOutput.innerHTML;
    this.value = '';
};
roomName =chatRoom.value;
var channel = new DataChannel('Session Unique Identifier'); 

channel.onopen = function(userid) {
    chatInput.disabled = false;
    chatInput.value = 'Hi, ' + userid;
    chatInput.focus();
};

channel.onmessage = function(message, userid) {
    chatOutput.innerHTML = userid + ': ' + message + '<hr />' 
                         + chatOutput.innerHTML;
};

channel.onleave = function(userid) {
    chatOutput.innerHTML = userid + ' Left.<hr />' 
                         + chatOutput.innerHTML;
};


var websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/events/');
    channel.openSignalingChannel = function (config) {
        config.channel = config.channel || this.channel;

        websocket.channel = config.channel;
        websocket.onopen = function() {
            console.log("in onopen");// code is not reached for some reason
           // console.log(JSON.stringify({open: true,channel: config.channel}));
            websocket.push(JSON.stringify({
                open: true,
                channel: config.channel,
                op : "JoinRoom",
                RoomName : roomName

            }));
            if (config.callback)
                config.callback(websocket);
        };
        websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
            config.onmessage(JSON.parse(event.data));
        };
        websocket.push = websocket.send;
        websocket.send = function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify({data: data,channel: config.channel}));
            websocket.push(JSON.stringify({
                data: data,
                channel: config.channel
            }));
        };
     };
</script>
```

And for my WebSocketServer:

```
@WebSocket
@ServerEndpoint(value="/events/")
public class SignallingSocket  extends WebSocketHandler{
private static Map<String,ArrayList<Session>> rooms = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Session>>(); //Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
Session sess;
String currentRoom="NOTSET";
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String message) {
    //sess.getContainer().
    System.out.println("I just got " + message);
    Map json;
    try {
        json = (Map)parser.parse(message);
        String op = json.get("op").toString();
        if(op.equals("JoinRoom")){
            currentRoom = json.get("RoomName").toString();
            if(!rooms.containsKey(currentRoom)){
                rooms.put(currentRoom, new ArrayList<Session>());
            }
            ArrayList<Session> othersInRoom = rooms.get(currentRoom);
            for (Session otherPeer : othersInRoom) {
                 try{
                     otherPeer.getBasicRemote().sendText("Tell other peers in the room this new person has joined"); //How???
                  } catch (Exception ex) {
                      System.out.println("Broadcast error: "+ex.getMessage());
                  } 
            }
            sess.getBasicRemote().sendText("Tell this new peer about others already in the room");//How???
            rooms.get(currentRoom).add(sess);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Broadcast error: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return "{\"someresponse\":\"What should i return\"}";
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen (Session peer) { //This works
    this.sess = peer;
    System.out.println("A client connected");

}


@OnClose
public void onClose(Session peer) {
    //peers.remove(peer); 
    rooms.get(currentRoom).remove(peer);
    ArrayList<Session> othersInRoom = rooms.get(currentRoom);
    if(othersInRoom.size()==0){
        rooms.remove(currentRoom);
    }else{
        for (Session otherPeer : othersInRoom) {
             try{
                 otherPeer.getBasicRemote().sendText("Tell other peers in the room this person has left");//How???
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  System.out.println("Broadcast error: "+ex.getMessage());
              } 
        }
    }
}

@OnError
public void onError(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}

//@Override
public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
    factory.register(SignallingSocket.class);

}

}
```

Comment: Here is how to use any WebSockets server: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/Signaling.md#example-code-to-explain-how-to-override-opensignalingchannel A demo snippet: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/Signaling.md#any-websocket-server-for-signaling

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any code samples for a Java WebSocket server?

Comment: I've abandoned WebRTC for this project. Websockets only will be sufficient and using a p2p system for this type of game didn't make any sense anyway